# Spring JDBC Template Conditional Insert

Tags: sql, spring, spring-jdbc

I am trying to write a conditional batch insert based on Java Parameters, for example

```
List<Object[]> params = new ArrayList();
params.add(new Object[]{1, 2, 3});

getSimpleJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
"INSERT INTO SomeTable( colA, colB, colC)" +
 " VALUES(?, ?, ?)" +
 " WHERE EXISTS ( // some condition )", params);
```

This obviously does not work, and the closest example I have found involves
selecting the INSERT values from tables, instead of the List arguments, which is what I need. How can I reference the Object[] parameters as part of the INSERT values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you should move this condition in a separate SELECT.

Comment: Can you provide an example? The problem with SELECT, is that I believe I have to be referencing table values, whereas I just want to reference the parameter java variables.

Answer (score 0):

As your example, you should try following syntax and the **SimpleJdbcOperations.update** method:

```
getSimpleJdbcTemplate.update(
    " INSERT INTO SomeTable( colA, colB, colC)" +
    " SELECT srcA, srcB, srcC" +
    " FROM src_table" +
    " WHERE EXISTS ( // some condition )",
    params
);
```

Additionally, I've been using [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) for generation of dynamic SQL. It's the best language I ever use.

for Example(As StringTemplate Syntax):

```
StringTemplate tmpl = new StringTemplate(
    " SELECT *" +
    " FROM some_table" +
    " WHERE 1 = 1" +
    "$search_age:{ AND age = ?}$" +
    "$search_name:{ AND name = ?}$"
);


/**
 * if param_age is not null, "AND age = ?" would be included in argumented sql,
 * same as param_name
 */
tmpl.setAttribute("age", param_age);
tmpl.setAttribute("name", param_name);
// :~)

String sqlTmpl = tmpl.toString(); // final SQL generated
```